# Switching homeowners insurance - are there any considerations to take into account during the transition period?

Tags: home-ownership, home-insurance

My current homeowner's insurance has bungled a recent repair and I'm ready to move to a new company. I have done the research and found a firm that I feel very comfortable with. I'm planning to switch next month but I want to see if there are any caveats or potential issues that may arise from switching.

Of course I'll read any documents that are sent over, but I'm looking for advice on anything in particular that I should be aware of that are part of the switching process, not just a different policy. I'm thinking of something like no preexisting conditions, a waiting period for anything that happens within the first X days, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The last time I changed insurance companies for home insurance, I found out that I needed a home inspection before the insurance company would underwrite the policy.  I don't know if this was a policy of my new insurance company or if it was a  new state regulation.  Either way, find out if your new insurance company requires an inspection and make sure that it is done, approved and that you are ready to go before cancelling the previous policy.

I would also check to see if there are any black out periods for underwriting.  I don't recall the exact details but if there are any tropical storms within X miles of the state, Florida (or perhaps only specific Florida insurance companies) will not green light a new policy until the storm has passed.